# How to convert from type System.string [][] to type System.Iconvertible?

Tags: c#, tcp

I am working on a TCP/IP networking where I get information from a camera and I have to do some math before I send it to the robot via a plugin.

Camera's raw string which comes into this client-side is

> "0000L000000651\r\n0000"
>   "17.617889;87.416702;51.491058;121.289856;+0.481;;89.154221;47.625900;123.027390;81.499069;+0.524\r\n;

In the code, I used one if loop `(if (readByCount > 30)` so that I dont get "0000L000000651\r\n0000" so because of this if loop I get only 2nd string which is

> "17.617889;87.416702;51.491058;121.289856;+0.481;;89.154221;47.625900;123.027390;81.499069;+0.524\r\n;

This string contains information of two regions of interest (ROI) separates by two semicolons(;;). That's why I used split method twice, once by (;;) and once by (;). Until this point, everything is fine. By after that, I want to convert that into array of double and it is giving me an error that type System.string [][] to type System.Iconvertible

I used the code:

```
 public async void ReadDataAsync(TcpClient mClient)
    {try
        {
            StreamReader clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(mClient.GetStream());

            char [] buff = new char[1024];
            int readByCount = 0;


            while (true)
            {
                readByCount = await clientStreamReader.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length);

                Directory.CreateDirectory("Camera o3D1");

                if (readByCount <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from Server.");
                    mClient.Close();
                    break;
                }
                if (readByCount > 30)
                {
                    var output = (new string(buff).TrimEnd('\u0000'));
                    Debug.WriteLine(output);


                    Debug.WriteLine(output.GetType());

                    var output1 = output.Split(new[] { ";;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(';')).ToArray();

                    Debug.WriteLine(output1);
                    foreach (var item in output1[0])
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(item));
                        Debug.WriteLine(item.GetType());
                    }




                    //JToken jsonParsed = JToken.FromObject(output1);
                    //Debug.WriteLine(jsonParsed);
                    //Debug.WriteLine(jsonParsed.GetType());



                    //foreach (var item in jsonParsed)
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine(jsonParsed.);
                    //}

                }


                    //File.WriteAllLines("Camera o3D1/file.json", jsonParsed);
                    //File.AppendAllText("Camera o3D1/file.json", type);


                Array.Clear(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(excp.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And got output:

> > 17.644886;87.427452;51.513859;121.296410;+0.481;;89.176285;47.627792;123.045242;81.496758;+0.524;;

```
System.String
System.String[][]
17644886
87427452
51513859
121296410
481
```

First I displayed the raw string then I split it and then displayed each component. But it is not double but an integer. 
I want that to have double and I want `17.644886;87.427452;51.513859;121.296410;+0.481` in one array so basically I want array of array and each array should contain `17.644886;87.427452;51.513859;121.296410;+0.481` like elements where if I access `output1[0]`, I should get `[17.64,87.42, 51.51, 121.29,.48]` and if I access `output1[0][0]`, I should get `17.64`. How to do that? Any ideas?

```
foreach (var item in output1[0][0])
{
    Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(item));
}
```

After using `foreach` loop a bit differently, I get an error:

> > Invalid cast from 'char' to 'double'

The numbers are not fixed. They are coordinates and they will be changed each item.

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: [Your Code here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XqAj1e). I just ran what you have and it shows correct decimal values

Comment: [With 2 decimal](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1w9aev)

Comment: can you tell us what goes into `buff` so we can recreate it

Comment: In my case, it's not happening. Even I am checking its data type after conversion. It is showing System.string

Comment: hi Vedant, can you edit question with value of `buff` f

Comment: I edited my post. I hope now it will give some more ideas about my problem.

Comment: It's not clear that this has anything to do with TCP. You will get more targeted responses if you can reduce your question as much as possible, into one like `string foo = "asdf"; parse_string(foo);`

Comment: I am getting the string via TCP/IP. Could that be the case that it's not behaving the way it should behave.